# Prism: Share ViewModel's property in parent ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, prism-4

I'm developing WPF Prism application using Unity container. The issue is: I have a `ListBox`, each element has it's own ViewModel. In that element I need to select a location from a list of locations. List of locations is the same for all elements. How could I share this list in the parent ViewModel?

On the internet I googled that I may:

1. Use `RegionContext`. But
   it's not right way (`RegionContext` could serve only one object, but I have not only locations).
2. Use `SharedService`. But, by my opinion, this way is more suitable
   for real-time data changing.

Is there the right way? Best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is always going to be the same, I usually use a Static class

```
public static class Lists
{
    public static List<Location> Locations {get; set;}

    static Lists()
    {
        Lists = DAL.GetLocations();
    }
}
```

Then in my XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Lists.Locations}}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentLocation}" />
```

Comment: accepted you answer but since I don't like static classes/properties I use shared services.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Rachels solution you can create a new view model for the list and insert an instance of this view model into your IoC container. Every view model that resolves this list view model via the container will then get a reference to this single instance.